# visual c++ run java class as process

Tags: java, c++

Something like NativeJ which is able to run Java application as myjava.exe in the task manager instead of displaying as java.exe. Please advice how do I code it from scratch in Visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Java invocation API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html).

Comment: I'm unfamiliar to JNI, will take a look. Thanks.